# Split list with colon seperated items into list of tuples

Tags: python, list, split, tuples

If I have the following list:

> ['Host: www.perdu.com', 'Connection: keep-alive', 'Cache-Control:
>   max-age=0', 'Accept:
>   text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
>   'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_4)
>   AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/38.0.2125.111
>   Safari/537.36', 'DNT: 1', 'Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch',
>   'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,es;q=0.6,fr;q=0.4', '']

How can I end up with a list of tuples `tuple_list` like:

```
tuples_list = [
    ('Host', 'www.perdu.com'),
    ('Connection', 'keep-alive'),
     ....
]
```

Comment: Why do you want to go to a list of tuples?  Would going to a dictionary or an OrderedDict be more usable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you heard of [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)?

```
headers = ['Host: www.perdu.com', 'Connection: keep-alive', 'Cache-Control: max-age=0', 'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,/;q=0.8', 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/38.0.2125.111 Safari/537.36', 'DNT: 1', 'Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch', 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,es;q=0.6,fr;q=0.4', '']
headers = [i.split(': ') for i in headers]
```

will return you:

```
[['Host', 'www.perdu.com'], ['Connection', 'keep-alive'], ['Cache-Control', 'max-age=0'], ['Accept', 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,/;q=0.8'], ['User-Agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/38.0.2125.111 Safari/537.36'], ['DNT', '1'], ['Accept-Encoding', 'gzip,deflate,sdch'], ['Accept-Language', 'en-US,en;q=0.8,es;q=0.6,fr;q=0.4'], ['']]
```

you can get a list of tuples if you do this instead:

```
headers = ['Host: www.perdu.com', 'Connection: keep-alive', 'Cache-Control: max-age=0', 'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,/;q=0.8', 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/38.0.2125.111 Safari/537.36', 'DNT: 1', 'Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch', 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,es;q=0.6,fr;q=0.4', '']
headers = [tuple(i.split(': ')) for i in headers]
```

this will return what you expect:

```
[('Host', 'www.perdu.com'), ('Connection', 'keep-alive'), ('Cache-Control', 'max-age=0'), ('Accept', 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,/;q=0.8'), ('User-Agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/38.0.2125.111 Safari/537.36'), ('DNT', '1'), ('Accept-Encoding', 'gzip,deflate,sdch'), ('Accept-Language', 'en-US,en;q=0.8,es;q=0.6,fr;q=0.4'), ('',)]
```

Comment: You code leaves the space in the second item of the tuple.

Answer (score 4):

How about:

```
tuples_list = [tuple(item.split(": ")) for item in thelist]
```

This uses a list comprehension to iterate over each item in the list, split it at the `:`, and converts each of those resulting arrays to a tuple.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `split(':')` in a list comprehension to accomplish that.

```
>>> tuples_list = [tuple(i.split(':')) for i in l]
>>> tuples_list
[('Host', ' www.perdu.com'),
 ('Connection', ' keep-alive'),
 ('Cache-Control', ' max-age=0'),
 ('Accept', ' text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,/;q=0.8'),
 ('User-Agent', ' Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/38.0.2125.111 Safari/537.36'),
 ('DNT', ' 1'),
 ('Accept-Encoding', ' gzip,deflate,sdch'),
 ('Accept-Language', ' en-US,en;q=0.8,es;q=0.6,fr;q=0.4')]
```